# Syntax error - how to get value of textbox

Tags: javascript, textbox

I have a trouble getting value from text box. Conventional javascript getElementByName returns error :undefined. I was able to use jQuery in other examples with select. But can't find a reference anywhere about input tags. This line shows syntax error:

```
  var total = = $('input[name='+formQty+'] :text').val();
```

What is a jquery for picking value/text of a textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand your query selector is incorrect.

It should be `'input[name='+formQty+']:text'` the `:text` as you have it is trying to select any text elements underneath the current input resulting in nothing. You can even get rid of the `:text` and only select the element based on name.  `.val()` should then work if you have properly selected the input element.

You should also debug this by just performing the $('...') method without the function call and see what elements are returned.

Comment: Thanks @mistagrooves. .val() without text worked: var total = $('input[name='+formQty+']').val(); Now I have a challenge to displayed another value there. I tried to use $('input[name='+formQty+']').val() = sum; and document.MainForm.elements["formQty"].value = sum; Both didn't work. Is there another method for this?

Answer (score 2):

you have 2 equal signs.

```
var total = $('input[name='+formQty+'] :text').val();
```

It might be easier also to stick an ID attribute on the `input` tag and use this

```
var total = $('#myInputId').val();
```

make sure you are calling it from a loaded dom:

```
$(function() {
   var total = $('#myInputId').val();
});
```

Comment: I don't have Id of element unfortunately, only name.

Comment: maybe try accessing it through the form: myform.elements[ formQty ].value

Comment: calling from this HTML: <input type="text" name="QTY.1-DAY-ACUVUE" size="3" maxlength="8" onkeydown="javascript:QtyEnabledAddToCart();" value="1"> . I tried myform.elements method and problem was even worse - script was not returning nothing, not even "undefined". I had similar issues with select elements and the only thing that worked there was this: var fselected = $('select[name='+selectRightName+'] option:selected'); I am looking for similar way to get input value.

Comment: @Alexica don't actually use 'myform', use the name of your form.

Comment: thanks, I figured that. This problem solved by using .val() and removing :text. Thanks @Daniel for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your problem getting this to work with `getElementByName()` - that's probably because the method is actually `getElementsByName()` - note the plural elementS. It returns a list of all elements with the specified name, accessible via array syntax; even if there is only one matching element you still get a list (with only one thing in it).

If you are sure there will be exactly one element with the specified name you can do this:

```
var elementValue = document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value;
```